# SMTP forwarding services?

Tags: email, services, smtp

I have my own server on the internet, which runs a SMTP server to forward emails for multiple domains to other email accounts (gmail, yahoo,...). But my server is not very reliable since I do experimental development on it.

Therefore I would like to use a reliable SMTP server which would accept Emails for my domains and forward them to configured addresses. I would change the MX DNS records of my domains to this SMTP server, of course.

Where can I get an affordable SMTP server where I can configure multipe forwardings for multiple domains?

*I know, I could use Google Apps for this, but I would have to create an user account for each address to forward. And these accounts would have to be assigned with the email address. And this would prevent the recievers from having an own Gmail account and have the address assigned to it. So they would not be able to use it as their sender address when using their private Gmail accounts.*

Comment: If you are willing to run your own server, all the major Unix mail server products can do this (e.g., postfix, qmail, exim, etc.), or on the Windows OS side I'd use Mercury/32 by David Harris:  http://www.pmail.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't adverse to doing a bit of unix and smtp administration of your own, a small linux VPS running an authenticated SMTP service would likely be your best bet. Cheap VPSen can currently be had for $5-10/month depending on your needs.